# Google Sheet App Script - How to only setValues only unique values

Tags: google-apps-script

In this spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1givNbMvgzD8lbk6NAcwjkpp4-A_D8MetltHjEpinOAI/edit#gid=0

I'd like to Combine only unique `Links` and `Category` into `Combined` sheet.

Right now, with my script, it can only combine all existing data:

```
function combine() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var allsheets = ss.getSheets();
    var sourceID = '1givNbMvgzD8lbk6NAcwjkpp4-A_D8MetltHjEpinOAI';
    var targetID = '1givNbMvgzD8lbk6NAcwjkpp4-A_D8MetltHjEpinOAI';

    var sheetExclude = ["Combined"];
    var sheetExcludeIndex = new Array(sheetExclude.length);

    for (var s in allsheets) {
        var sheet = allsheets[s];
        for (var e in sheetExclude) {
            if (String(sheet.getName() == sheetExclude[e])) {
                sheetExcludeIndex[e] = sheet.getIndex;

            }
        }
    }


    allsheets.splice(sheetExcludeIndex, sheetExclude.length);

    for (var s in allsheets) {
        var sheet = allsheets[s];
        updateSourceToTarget(sourceID, sheet.getName(), targetID, 'Combined');
    }
}

function updateSourceToTarget(sourceID, sourceName, targetID, targetname) {
    Logger.log(sourceID + ' ' + sourceName + ' ' +targetname);
    var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceID).getSheetByName(sourceName);
    var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetID).getSheetByName(targetname);
    var sourcelastRow = source.getLastRow();
    var sourcelastCol = source.getLastColumn();
    var destinationlastRow = destination.getLastRow();
    var destinationlastCol = destination.getLastColumn();
    var sourcedata = source.getRange(2, 9, sourcelastRow, 10).getValues();


    destination.getRange(destinationlastRow + 1, 2, sourcelastRow, sourcelastCol).setValues(sourcedata);
}
```

However, I'd like to only combine unique links from `Sheet2` and `Sheet3`:

**In red is unique data**

Sheet2: 
[image]

Sheet3:
[image]

How can I efficiently add only unique values to `Combined` from `Sheet2`& `Sheet3`?

Comment: Why are those links not in red not unique?

Comment: Ah my wording was not clear, what I mean is not unique in the sheet `Combined` since the ones not in red already exists there.

Comment: You shouldve provided combined screenshot too. I'm sure you must have tried `=UNIQUE({Sheet1i:j;Sheet2!i:j})`. Any specific reason  you want a script?

Comment: Noted for next time on screenshots. I wanted to keep a static record of it since `Sheet2` & `Sheet3` updates every 5 minutes, and in `Combined` I have other attributes I'm keeping track of for each link, such as Title tag for the page, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to put the values, which removed the duplicated links, to the target sheet (in this case, it's `Combined` sheet.).
- The duplicated links are checked from the target sheet and source sheets. In this case, the target sheet and source sheets are `Combined`, `Sheet2` and `Sheet3`, respectively.

  - In your sample Spreadsheet, you want to put the following rows to the target sheet.

    - `https://thehill.com/policy/national-security/department-of-homeland-security/460158-new-hampshire-border-patrol  BorderSecurity`
    - `https://abcnews.go.com/International/climate-change-frontier-worlds-northernmost-town/story?id=65381362  ClimateChange`
- You want to achieve this by modifying your Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows. In this modification, your function of `updateSourceToTarget()` is not used.

#### From:

```
for (var s in allsheets) {
    var sheet = allsheets[s];
    updateSourceToTarget(sourceID, sheet.getName(), targetID, 'Combined');
}
```

#### To:

```
// Retrieve values from the target sheet.
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetExclude[0]);
var targetValues = targetSheet.getRange("B2:C" + targetSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();

// Retrieve values from all source sheets. <--- Modified
var sourceValues = allsheets.reduce(function(ar, sheet) {
  var v = sheet.getRange(2, 9, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 10).getValues().filter(function(r) {return r[0] && r[1]});
  if (v.length > 0) {
    v = v.filter(function(e) {return !ar.some(function(f) {return e[0] === f[0]})});
    Array.prototype.push.apply(ar, v);
  }
  return ar;
}, []);

// Remove the duplication values between the target sheet and all source sheets.
var dstValues = sourceValues.filter(function(e) {return !targetValues.some(function(f) {return e[0] === f[0]})});

// Add the result values to the target sheet.
if (dstValues.length > 0) {
  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetID).getSheetByName(sheetExclude[0]);
  destination.getRange(destination.getLastRow() + 1, 2, dstValues.length, dstValues[0].length).setValues(dstValues);
}
```

The flow of this modified script is as follows.

1. Retrieve values from the target sheet.
2. Retrieve values from all source sheets.
3. Remove the duplication values between the target sheet and all source sheets.
4. Add the result values to the target sheet.

#### Note:

- When your shared Spreadsheet is used as the target (`Combined`) and source sheets (`Sheet2` and `Sheet3`), the following rows are added to the target sheet.

  - `https://thehill.com/policy/national-security/department-of-homeland-security/460158-new-hampshire-border-patrol  BorderSecurity`
  - `https://abcnews.go.com/International/climate-change-frontier-worlds-northernmost-town/story?id=65381362  ClimateChange`

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

### Added:

In this additional script, a hash table is used for this situation, as mentioned by [TheMaster's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57831765/google-sheet-app-script-how-to-only-setvalues-only-unique-values/57832141?noredirect=1#comment102098806_57832141). For example, a sample can be also seen at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57766051). In your situation, at first, all values are retrieved from all sheets including `Combined` sheet, and the hash table is created. By this, the duplicated values are removed. Then, the converted values to an array are put to the Spreadsheet.

#### Sample script:

Please modify your script as follows.

From:

```
allsheets.splice(sheetExcludeIndex, sheetExclude.length);

for (var s in allsheets) {
    var sheet = allsheets[s];
    updateSourceToTarget(sourceID, sheet.getName(), targetID, 'Combined');
}
```

To:

```
// allsheets.splice(sheetExcludeIndex, sheetExclude.length); // In this script, this line is not used.

// Retrieve values from the target sheet.
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetExclude[0]);
var targetValues = targetSheet.getRange("B2:C" + targetSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();

// Retrieve values from all source sheets.
// Remove the duplication values between the target sheet and all source sheets.
var sourceValues = allsheets.reduce(function(obj, sheet) {
  var v = sheet.getRange(2, 9, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 10).getValues().filter(function(r) {return r[0] && r[1]});
  if (v.length > 0) v.forEach(function(e) {if (!(e[0] in obj)) obj[e[0]] = e[1]});
  return obj;
}, {});
var dstValues = Object.keys(sourceValues).map(function(e) {return [e, sourceValues[e]]});

// Add the result values to the target sheet.
if (dstValues.length > 0) {
  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetID).getSheetByName(sheetExclude[0]);
  destination.getRange(2, 2, destination.getLastRow(), 2).clearContent();
  destination.getRange(2, 2, dstValues.length, dstValues[0].length).setValues(dstValues);
}
```

- The proposed 2 sample scripts can be used for your situation. So please select one of them.

Comment: @Tanaike I've added more sheets and it looks like it's adding blank lines for some reason: https://i.imgur.com/DVzhDK2.png https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1givNbMvgzD8lbk6NAcwjkpp4-A_D8MetltHjEpinOAI/edit#gid=1603851111

Some sheets have empty values on `I` and `J` (with header) and all of them have some content between `A` to  `H` which needs to be ignored. I tried filtering `dstValues` with `dstValues.filter(String);` but it looks like it's still inputting blank lines. I'm not sure what's causing it.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for your comment. Yes. The hash table can also be used for this situation. I thought that the various answer might be helpful many users. So I thought that adding that method might be more useful. So also I added it, just now. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @sojim2 Thank you for replying. The reason of your new issue is the last row of the column "I" is different from that of other columns, and there are no values in the column "I" and "J". I couldn't notice about your actual specification. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. I updated my answer by modifying my script. Could you please confirm it? I modified my 1st script. And I added one more script.

Comment: you don't have poor skill, rather amazing skill, I love your answers!! I will check this if it works for my use case. Thank you so very much!

Comment: this script works beautifully as intended, I'm wondering instead of clearing the content, can we incrementally add to the `Combined` sheet? That way, even if `Sheet2` & `Sheet3` has new links and don't have old links anymore, the `Combined` sheet still has old links after combining.

Comment: Ah I was able to achieve what I've described above. Code will be in the update section of original post.

Comment: @sojim2 Yes. The 1st sample script, which was modified, is for adding the values. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could study from your question. Thank you, too.